# Adding multiple textareas to database php/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a form that submits 7 textareas that are each text for a day of the week. (shows specials for bars by day) Right now I am using the following code to submit it to the database. Is there an easier way (using arrays, or a for loop) to do this function?

```
$special_0 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['special_0']));
$special_1 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['special_1']));
$special_2 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['special_2']));
$special_3 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['special_3']));
$special_4 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['special_4']));
$special_5 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['special_5']));
$special_6 = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_POST['special_6']));


mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special) VALUES('.$bid.','0','.$special_0.')') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special) VALUES('.$bid.','1','.$special_1.')') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special) VALUES('.$bid.','2','.$special_2.')') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special) VALUES('.$bid.','3','.$special_3.')') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special) VALUES('.$bid.','4','.$special_4.')') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special) VALUES('.$bid.','5','.$special_5.')') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special) VALUES('.$bid.','6','.$special_6.')') or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can string all the inserts into one commit:

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week,special)
VALUES('.$bid.','0','.$special_0.'),
('.$bid.','1','.$special_1.'),
('.$bid.','2','.$special_2.'),
('.$bid.','3','.$special_3.'),
('.$bid.','3','.$special_4.'),
('.$bid.','3','.$special_5.'),
('.$bid.','3','.$special_6.');
```

Comment: ok, thanks. I also have a table of weekdays that has week_number and week_day. Is there a way to recurse through that and have just one insert line?

Comment: Not sure without seeing your code.

Also, you may want to use a cleaner php format:

    $sql = "INSERT INTO specials (bid, day_of_week, special)
        VALUES ('{$bid}','0','{$special_1}')";
    mysql_query($sql);